# Show wordpress content into one smartphone screen

Tags: android, css, wordpress, browser, smartphone

I worked on small personal site and integrated custom footer widgets. On desktop all is fine, but when load on smartphone, site can be scrolled by finger if move to left. To show better with image from smartphone directly.

**How should be** (without option to scroll left and right)

[image]

and **how is now** (when swipe with finger to left) is showing white screen. Looks bad.

[image]

So my question is how to make the same [like](https://videolofty.com) here for ex. This is [URL](https://videolofty.com/real-estate-video-production/) where issue is persisted.

Answer (score 1):

Margin-left is 150px in footer, even on small devices, pushing content out of view. Perhaps try the following:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {#footer-sidebar{margin-left:15px!important} }
```

Comment: In your wordpress theme, go to wp-admin, then appearance > customise from sidebar, then in custom codes or additional css, add the following

.footer-area{width:100%!important;}
Then, if you have caching plugin, clear caches. Open in incognito window on phone / private mode and see if fixed, please let me know if not. I am having difficulty replicating issue myself it seems to be okay for me but the above might fix it for you.

Comment: I followed your instructions and added that CSS but still can swipe to left and see white space.

Comment: @media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {#footer-sidebar{margin-left:15px!important}}

May also be a good idea to add the above. Your margin left is far to wide even on small screen, pushing content over the side. The above will reduce margin on small screens. 
If it doesn't work, just remove and someone else may be able to advise :-)
Add to same place as the width:100% - just to confirm, theres two sets of open and close curly brackets in the above, please make sure you dont miss any out ;)

Comment: Tryed that also, but still right empty space is visible, when swipe with screen.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this solved my issue:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
#footer-sidebar1 {float:left!important;
}
#footer-sidebar2 {float:left!important;
}
#footer-sidebar3 {float:left!important;
}
#footer-sidebar {
    margin-left:60px!important;
}
}
```